# Change the color of legend elements in ggplot (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2

Following is the sample code for the random chart:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=mpg,y=wt,color=factor(vs)))+geom_line()+theme(legend.position="top",legend.direction = "horizontal",legend.title=element_blank(),legend.key = element_blank())
```

and following is the output from above code:

[image]

My requirement: Instead of having two lines denoted by 0 and 1 as legend elements, I only want legend texts "0" and "1" colored as "red" and "skyblue" (same as color of lines) and remove the lines. Is this possible?

Comment: I tried to change the color with `guides(color = guide_legend(label.theme = element_text(colour = c("red", "skyblue"))))`, but it only returns the first value of the vector.

Comment: Thanks. But, it should automatically pick up the color, rather than entering the color as above. Plus, lines shouldn't be there once texts are colored.

Comment: for highest flexibility and least nuisance, I’d create a fake legend (just the numbers 1 /0) with geom_text and stitch this as plot to your main plot with the patchwork package. cannot make this at the moment because of work, but this should be super straightforward

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've written a [string legend guide](https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/articles/Miscellaneous.html#string-legends-1) in the ggh4x package, that you might find useful.

Example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=mpg,y=wt,color=factor(vs))) +
  guides(colour = "stringlegend") +
  geom_line() +
  theme(legend.position="top",
        legend.direction = "horizontal",
        legend.title=element_blank(),
        legend.key = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: It went completely under my radar that you have released ggh4x! I've always liked the package. So nice to know it is on CRAN now. Congrats!

Comment: @teunbrand Thank you. Does this all work when we are mixing two charts: like bar and line?

Comment: Yeah it should just work like a regular legend with just a colour/fill aesthetic, wherein the colour is applied to the text.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`ggtext`](https://github.com/wilkelab/ggtext) package which has `element_markdown()` function that allows text formatting

> The ggtext package provides simple Markdown and HTML rendering for ggplot2. Under the hood, the package uses the gridtext package for the actual rendering, and consequently it is limited to the feature set provided by gridtext.

> Support is provided for Markdown both in theme elements (plot titles, subtitles, captions, axis labels, legends, etc.) and in geoms (similar to geom_text()). In both cases, there are two alternatives, one for creating simple text labels and one for creating text boxes with word wrapping.

```r
library(RColorBrewer)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

my_col <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(unique(mtcars$vs), 'Dark2')

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt, color = factor(vs))) +
  geom_line() +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16) +
  theme(
    legend.position = "top", legend.direction = "horizontal",
    legend.title = element_blank(), legend.key = element_blank()
  )

p +
  scale_color_manual(
    labels = paste(
      "<span style='color:",
      my_col,
      "'>",
      unique(mtcars$vs),
      "</span>"
    ),
    values = my_col
  ) +
  theme(legend.text = element_markdown(size = 16)) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c(NA, NA))))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. But I will wait for alternatives approach.

Answer (score 1):

teunbrands custom guide is awesome. Just for completeness sake, here the fake legend option.

Technically, a legend is a very specific type of plot annotation. One of the most frequently asked questions is "how do I annotate outside the plot area" - which you can almost always answer with "create a second plot and stitch it to the main plot". Same here.

It requires a couple of tricks, in particular use of `geom_blank` for scaling, and then correct use of theme elements, which you can either pass to each plot or globally (with `&`)

The disadvantage of this approach is that you need to fiddle around with the coordinates to get the position right. but this should not be too much of an issue, except if you need to automate this.

<sub>P.S. the colors you are showing are neither "steelblue" nor "red" ... ;)</sub>

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p_main <- 
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt, color = factor(vs))) +
  geom_line() 

# semi - manual - chose x and y depending on the position relative to the other plot
# for labels: I used as.character just to be very explicit
df_legend <- data.frame(x = c(22,24), y = 3, labels = as.character(0:1))

p_legend <- 
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) + 
  geom_blank() +
  geom_text(data = df_legend, aes(x, y, label = labels, color = labels)) +
    theme_void() 

p_legend / p_main &
  plot_layout(heights = c(1, 10)) &
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>